# Getting error in react app -> " export 'MessageTeam' (imported as 'MessageTeam') was not found in 'stream-chat-react' "

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

I am using stream api to create a chat app. But getting this error while importing MessageTeam i.e a inbuild component in stream-chat-react.

```
import React from "react";
import { MessageTeam, useMessageContext } from "stream-chat-react";

const TeamMessage = () => {
  const { message } = useMessageContext();

  return (
    <MessageTeam
      message={{ ...message, user: {} }}
    />
  );
};

export default TeamMessage;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bro found the solution use MessageSimple instead worked great for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`MessageTeam` component was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/commit/9d75fb892e20cbdfd705cc94210c2ae12a5f9650).

Refer [documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/) for latest components.

Answer (score 0):

**MessageTeam** is not more supported for Stream V10, try unistalling V10 and install V9. It should sove your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageTeam` component is removed use the `Message` component which works almost same as  `MessageTeam`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Message , useMessageContext } from 'stream-chat-react';

const TeamMessage = () => {
    const { handleOpenThread, message } = useMessageContext();

    return (
        <Message 
            message={{ ...message, user: {}}}
        />
    )
}

export default TeamMessage
```